# How to duplicate a VST on Mac?

Tags: vst, plugin, plug-in, multiple, memory

I want to use a sampler that can only address a maximum amount of RAM, but I want to add even more instruments. If I duplicate the .component or the .vst inside the Plugin folder, it still shows up as one plugin inside my DAW. I can launch multiple instances of that plugin, but every instance share the same address space (I can't get past the RAM limit)

I tried to use jBridge, without success. Is it even possible to duplicate a plugin?

Comment: Ok, after hacking around, I was able to bypass the problem by changing the VST id inside the configuration file of my DAW. I tried to change the id of the VST itself with a hex editor, but no success (changed the ID in all the files of the VST if you right-click "Show package content"). I just can't find where that id is stored!! I also changed the VST name for more clarity inside my DAW (again with the hex editor).
The id must be encoded in some type that the hex editor can't find...

I was able to find the ID by using MuLab, but there are other tools if you google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the trick was to find the ID in reverse, as explained here: https://www.soundonsound.com/sound-advice/resolving-vst-plug-conflicts

So if you want to duplicate your AU/VST (I only tested VST, but AU should work the same I suppose), follow this:

-find the ID of your plug-in, I used MuLab (load the plugin, right click and "Show info"). Also get the name of the plugin in MuLab

-Go to your Plugins folder, duplicate the plugin, rename it, and right-click and "Show Package Contents"

-Go to Contents/MacOS

-Open the binary with a hex editor (like HexFiend)

-Search the string as text, but backwards (if, for example, your id is ZjQ4, look for 4QjZ)

-"Replace All" with 4 letters at random, and save the file

-Rescan the plugins in your DAW and you should be good! (I personally needed to trash the preference files of my DAW because the old ID persisted)

You can also change the plugin-name using the hex editor, if you want to differentiate between the original plug-in and the duplicate. You can find the original name using MuLab.

Edit: Actually you are required to change the name of the plugin in the binary, or else it won't load (at least for me). Look for two strings before the first ID occurence.